# Is "aws s3api list-objects-v2" supposed to be very slow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a bucket with 32,000,000 objects, and I wanted to see all files created on a certain date.

I did this:

`aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket MY_BUCKET --query 'Contents[?contains(LastModified,` 2021-01-20`)].Key'`

However, this has no been hanging for 15 minutes and I would like to know if this is to be expected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `list-objects-v2` API call only retrieves 1000 objects at a time, so it would be recursing through all your files.

The `--query` is applied locally, so it would be making 32,000 API calls.

For so many objects in a bucket, I would instead recommend using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects.